# REPORT -Visual Studio 2012

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2012, reporting-services

I am new to report.Dataset patient is a dropdownlist.Here I want to add a NULL field so thaT if i select Null it must retrieve some values from database.How can i create a NULL field in The dropdownbox of a report as below.But it is not working for me
http://msprojectnow.com/blog/reports-in-ssrs-with-multi-value-parameters-and-null-values

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are talking about a report parameter and that you intend to use Reporting Services Server to host the report. I usually find the approach below works to give provide an empty value to pick. So you add a dataset for the patient dropdown and use the query below as the data source for example.

```
select 0 as PatientID, ''as Patient
Union
Select PatientID, Patient
Order By Patient
```

Then you select Query as you source for your Patient parameter pick this data source and choose patientID as the value and Patient as the display value. If you do the same for default value but just pick Patient id, the bank value will show as your initial selection when you run the report.